# How to solve : ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

It's my first time with stored procedures in Oracle.

I have the following .Net class :

```
    Public Class Class1
        Public Shared Function StoredProcedure1() As String
            Return "coucou"
        End Function
    End Class
```

I want to use this class from Oracle. I followed the steps to deploy the class on Visual Studio. The deployment was successful.

Now when I go on Oracle and I query :

```
select STOREDPROCEDURE1 from dual
```

I'm getting the error :

```
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CLR", line 243
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CLR", line 42
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CLR", line 236
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.STOREDPROCEDURE1", line 6
02019. 00000 -  "connection description for remote database not found"
```

I don't understand where this error is coming from. I'm not using any database link in this function or whatever.

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks

Comment: There might be a view that is using corrupted database link

Comment: Did you check that CLR host is running and that entries are present for it in Tnsnames.ora and Listener.ora files?

Comment: @astentx thanks for your answer. What should I check exactly on Tnsnames.ora and Listener.ora please ? Should I add something to these files ?

Comment: You can check this [documentation article](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/clrnt/install.html) and compare it with the steps you've already performed in your DBMS. As described in the architecture, I've thought there's something with communication between DB and CLR.